# How can I add a node in XML file from TextBox using XmlDataProvider in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmldataprovider

I want to add a node named list under product node.

code in xaml is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Name="myDP" x:Key="MyData" Source="Product.xml" XPath="products" 
                     IsAsynchronous="False" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True"
                     PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

the addIdtm_button is:

```
 private void addItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         XmlDataProvider provider = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("MyData");
         XmlNode elmnt = provider.Document.CreateElement("item");
         elmnt.InnerText = itemTextBox.Text;

         provider.Document.ChildNodes[0].AppendChild(elmnt);
     }
     catch (Exception d)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(d.Message);
     }
 }
```

When button is clicked, the MessageBox is displayed: 
"The current node cannot contain other nodes."

what can I do now???

Comment: Is Product Node your root node?

Comment: Product.xml file is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
  <product id="li">
    <list >first</list>
    <list >second</list>
    <list >third</list>
    <list >fourth</list>
  </product>
</products>

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the first child of the document. `provider.Document.ChildNodes[0]` will return `XmlDeclaration, Value="version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"`. So instead use `provider.Document.ChildNodes[1]` which will return products node.

After modifying your code your `addItem_Click_1` looks like this:

```
private void addItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        XmlDataProvider provider = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("MyData");
        XmlNode elmnt = provider.Document.CreateElement("list");
        elmnt.InnerText = itemTextBox.Text;            
        (provider.Document.ChildNodes[1]).ChildNodes[0].AppendChild(elmnt);
        // Assuming that your XML file is in the same directory as you exe. If not, then 
        // give the right path as parameter to Save
        provider.Document.Save("Product.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(d.Message);
    }
}
```

In the above code, `provider.Document.ChildNodes[1]` will return `products` node from the XML file. `(provider.Document.ChildNodes[1]).ChildNodes[0]` will return `product` node to which you should `AppendChild`

Comment: Product.xml file is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <products> <product id="li"> <list >first</list> <list >second</list> <list >third</list> <list >fourth</list> </product> </products>

Comment: It is working but not saving in the .xml file. How can i do that please?